# Mouse malfunction with beeping noise

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad

I have been having an extremely annoying problem for a couple of months now. My mouse spontaniously stops responding to clicks and scrolling and instead causes a beeping sound (from the speakers) for every click or scroll I do.

This happens randomly but most often when I game, doesn’t matter which game though. The only thing thats affected is the mouse as I’m able to do everything with the keyboard. I have scanned my computer for viruses and malware and haven’t found anything, tried reinstalling the drivers and updated and such with no difference. I’ve tried switching my mouse, unplugging, plugging it in again, unplug and plug in another mouse etc… even tried with a touchpad and the problem persists. The only thing I can do to fix it is to restart the computer. I have searched alot for the problem and found some similar ones but nothing that can provide a solution.

Has anyone got any idea what to do about this?

System specs:

- **OS:** Windows 8.1
- **CPU:** i5 4670K
- **GPU:** Asus 280x DC2T
- **RAM:** 16GB
- **Motherboard:** Asus Z87-A

Comment: did you every try a different USB port?

Comment: From what you describe, your problem isn't the mouse or other pointing device, it is what some program is trying to do with the input or doesn't want to accept that input.

Comment: I've tried several kinds of mouse devices in all usb ports, and yes, it feels like a program is intercepting the input and just beeps, sort of the way the keyboard reacts to a popup but I've thouroghly searched for that program and I can't find it

Comment: Windows gives you this beep to let you know that you are producing mouse or keyboard inputs faster than the system can process them. This is usually caused by an application that is not reading input sufficiently quickly but could also be due to driver bugs, overheating, or misbehaving applications.

Answer (score 1):

Were you gaming using an XBox controller? If so, it's a driver problem.

I just found it [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/49niwd/my_pc_hangs_forever_every_time_i_quit_the_division/d0t8zo8), and the instructions are fairly simple:

- Download proper driver from [THIS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v3f04cmle7rol6/Xbox_Wireless_Adapter_for_Windows_7-8.1_x64_6_3_9600_16384.rar?dl=0) link
- Open Control Panel / Device Manager
- Expand `Human Interface Devices`
- Find `XINPUT Compatible HID Device`
- Go Properties / Driver / Update Driver
- Browse My Computer
- Point to the folder you de-compressed the driver
- Choose XINPUT Driver

Voilà, you might no longer have this annoying problem. Worked for me.

if the link with the updated driver stops work, I'd suggest to ask at the original community where this problem was solved, (first link).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a compatibility issue and not an issue with mouse hardware. 
Windows 8.1 introduced changes to mouse input processing for low-latency interaction scenarios. Therefore, games respond to mouse inputs differently in Windows 8.1 than in earlier versions of Windows. Hence please refer to below Microsoft article to troubleshoot the compatibility issue in Windows 8.1.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows